# Manage number of thread execution in Spring Async Task Executor for a specific method

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I'm using spring  Async task in my application and I have a problem with a task that requires all the server resources.
In particularly I have this configuration:

```
@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

And I'm using aync task on three method, two are very simple and fast but one is complex because it creates a process where a Matlab routine take from few seconds to several minutes and a huge amount ofe resources. So only for this task I would like to have one thread and put in queue all the other request to achieve a sequentially execution.
With the configuration above I manage all the threads of my application, is there a way to limit only the specific Async method?
If it is not possible the best solution could be to use a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) or [ExecutorServices](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to create another custom thread pool for specific long running task, so it does not block your threads from running.

```
@Bean(name= "myExecutor")
public Executor getCustomAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

And set it for your async method:

```
@Async("myExecutor")
```

Comment: thanks it seems to work. What I was wondering is why the first executor override the Executor method and the second no.

Comment: In your setting, your Executor is being used for all `@Async` method. All of your `@Async` still share the same pool so your long running method block other thread from executing. When setting `@Bean` and give it to specific `@Async`, your other method using the default executor you provided, why the specific `@Async` use the pointed pool only. They do not block each other